# MySQL: Optimizing and/or Differing From Derived Tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to optimize my query when utilizing a couple very large data sets. My current query takes a little while to process, even for only a couple days worth of data, whereas this would be intended to pull monthly data.

My question would be what is the best way to pull this off: (I have used one of the datasets in this example, but keep in mind there would be three with basically the same structure, all in the same query)

```
select u.id, u.name, 
  count(distinct(case when sales.tag='event' then sales.id end)) as 
   eventsales,
  count(distinct(case when sales.tag='onpremise' then sales.id end)) 
   as onpresales,
  count(distinct(case when sales.tag='offpremsales' then sales.id 
   end)) as offpresales,
  count(distinct(case when sales.fulfillment='yes' and 
   sales.premise='on' then sales.id end)) as fullonsales,
  count(distinct(case when sales.fulfillment='no' and 
   sales.premise='on' then sales.id end)) as fulloffsales
from users u
left join (
  select * from sales where org='XXXX' and invoicedate BEWTEEN '2018- 
  04-01' and '2018-04-10' and status='active'
 ) sales on sales.user=u.id
where u.status='active'

group by u.org, u.id, u.name

order by u.team
```

I am no pro, still learning, but is this optimal to perform?

Would it be better to ditch the derived table and utilize 5 subqueries?
Since there are only a couple subtle changes in each, should I create multiple derived tables instead?

Also, my index used in this example would be sales table: org, invoicedate, status
However, from my research, MySQL does not use indexes on derived tables. Is this accurate?

Thanks in advance, let me know if I need to provide any other info.
**Entire actual query below**

```
select t.name as team, u.name as "REP NAME", 
 count(distinct activity.id) as "TOTAL VISITS", 
 count(distinct activity.account_id) as "UNIQUE VISITS",
 ROUND((select sum(s.volumece) from lpmysqldb.sales s where 
  s.org_id='555b918ae4b07b6ac5050852' and s.account_id IN (select 
  account_id from lpmysqldb.activity where 
  org_id='555b918ae4b07b6ac5050852' and user_id=u.id and 
  (completed_at between '2018-04-01' and '2018-04-04') and 
  tag='visit' and accountname is not null and (status='active' or 
  status='true' or status='1')) and (s.invoice_date between 
  DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-01-01') and DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y- 
  %m-%d'))),2) as "CURRENT YEAR VOLUME",
 ROUND((select sum(s.volumece) from lpmysqldb.sales s where 
  s.org_id='555b918ae4b07b6ac5050852' and s.account_id IN (select 
  account_id from lpmysqldb.activity where 
  org_id='555b918ae4b07b6ac5050852' and user_id=u.id and 
  (completed_at between '2018-04-01' and '2018-04-04') and 
  tag='visit' and accountname is not null and (status='active' or 
  status='true' or status='1')) and (s.invoice_date between 
  (DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-01-01') - INTERVAL 1 YEAR) and 
  (DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-%d') - INTERVAL 1 YEAR))),2) as 
  "PREVIOUS YEAR VOLUME",

 count(distinct placement.id) as "COMMITMENTS ADDED",

 CASE WHEN 
  count(distinct activity.account_id) = 0 THEN (count(distinct 
   placement.id) / 1) 
  else (cast(count(distinct placement.id) as decimal(10,2)) / 
   cast(count(distinct activity.account_id) as decimal(10,2)))
 END as "UNIQUE VISIT TO COMMITMENT %",

 CASE WHEN o.mode='basic' then count(distinct placement.id) else 
  count(distinct(case when placement.commitmentstatus='fullfilled' 
  then placement.id end)) 
 END as "COMMITMENTS FULFILLED",

 CASE WHEN o.mode='basic' then 1 else 
  (CASE WHEN 
    count(distinct placement.id) = 0 THEN (count(distinct(case when 
    placement.commitmentstatus='fullfilled' then placement.id end)) / 
    1) 
    else (cast(count(distinct(case when 
    placement.commitmentstatus='fullfilled' then placement.id end)) 
    as decimal(10,2)) / cast(count(distinct placement.id) as 
    decimal(10,2)))
    end) 
  END as "COMMITMENT TO FULFILLMENT %",

  CASE WHEN o.mode='basic' then count(distinct placement.id) else 
   count(distinct(case when placement.commitmentstatus='fullfilled' 
   AND (premise = 1 or premise IS NULL) then placement.id end)) 
  END as "ON PREM COMMITMENTS FULFILLED",

  CASE WHEN o.mode='basic' then count(distinct placement.id) else 
   count(distinct(case when placement.commitmentstatus='fullfilled' 
   AND premise = 0 then placement.id end)) 
  END  

  CASE WHEN o.mode='basic' then count(distinct placement.id) else 
   count(distinct(case when placement.commitmentstatus='fullfilled' 
   AND ispackage IN ('1','true','active') then placement.id end)) 
  END as "PACKAGE COMMITMENTS FULFILLED",

  CASE WHEN o.mode='basic' then count(distinct placement.id) else 
   count(distinct(case when placement.commitmentstatus='fullfilled' 
   AND isdraft IN ('1','true','active') then placement.id end)) 
  END as "DRAFT COMMITMENTS FULFILLED",

  (select count(distinct id) from lpmysqldb.activity where 
    org_id='555b918ae4b07b6ac5050852' and user_id=u.id and 
    (completed_at between '2018-04-01' and '2018-04-04') and 
    activity_name IN ('Display','Floor Display') and (activity.status 
    IN ('1','active','true','') OR activity.status IS NULL)) as 
  "DISPLAYS BUILT",

  (select count(distinct id) from lpmysqldb.activity where 
    org_id='555b918ae4b07b6ac5050852' and user_id=u.id and 
    (completed_at between '2018-04-01' and '2018-04-04') and 
    tag='event' and (activity.status IN ('1','active','true','') OR 
    activity.status IS NULL)) as "EVENTS"

 from lpmysqldb.users u
 left join lpmysqldb.teams t on t.team_id=u.team_id
 left join lpmysqldb.organizations o on o.id=t.org_id
 left join (select * from lpmysqldb.activity where 
  org_id='555b918ae4b07b6ac5050852' and (completed_at between '2018- 
  04-01' and '2018-04-04') and tag='visit' and accountname is not 
  null and (status IN ('1','active','true','') OR status IS NULL)) 
  activity on activity.user_id=u.id
 left join (select * from lpmysqldb.placements where 
  orgid='555b918ae4b07b6ac5050852' and (placementdate between '2018- 
  04-01' and '2018-04-04') and (status IN ('1','active','true','') OR 
  status IS NULL)) placement on placement.userid=u.id

where u.org_id='555b918ae4b07b6ac5050852' 
  and u.status IN ('active','true','1')
  and istestuser!='1'
group by u.org_id, t.name, u.id, u.name, o.mode
order by t.name asc, count(distinct activity.id) desc
```

Comment: Why not suck it and see? FWIW, i don't think there's anything inherently poor in your approach. (Although 'BEWTEEN' is an obvious cause for concern)

Comment: I did.. It doesn't want to perform well. I can post the entire query below. On the note of between; is it better to do invoicedate >= startdate and invoicedate <= enddate???!?

Comment: First thing to try, I'd remove the subquery (select * from sales...) sales. It will create temporary table with no indexes. You can join directly with sales, and put all WHERE clauses together.

Comment: No, it's just better to spell it correctly.

Comment: @Strawberry HA i just typed that for an example..but thanks

Comment: @AlexanderEkzhanov ya i tried doing it that way too but was not getting any better with the result; left join sale on org='{{ org }}' ...  etc